# Ajax authentication using CURL request: Ionic app, Django, Rest, Oauth2

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, curl, oauth-2.0

I am successfully using a curl request to authenticate a user on my Django project with Django-social-auth using a Facebook token to return a token for my personal site. Quite simply, I have a Facebook token and I am converting it to a Django token in return, but I am only accomplishing this feat using a CURL request. The framework I am using comes from Philip Garnero (1).

The CURL request - curl -X POST -d "grant_type=convert_token&client_id=&client_secret=&backend=facebook&token=" http://localhost:8000/auth/convert-token

The confusion comes when I am trying to do this using an AJAX request.
Is there something wrong with the way my ajax is setup? Do I need to get a csrf token to begin with before I can convert my facebook token to a authenticated Django token?

Update: I am getting a 400 error unsupported_grant_type while running my ajax request through a proxy. The request is the same request I have successfully executing in both a curl command and a Postman command.

Ajax Request:

```
$http({
        url: "proxy/url/...",
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,  
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          "client_id": "...",
          "client_secret": "...",
          "grant_type": "password",
          "username": "...",
          "password": "..."
        },
        headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }        
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("error status = " + status);
            console.log(angular.toJson(data));
        });
```

(1) - https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

Comment: `is there something wrong with the way my ajax is setup?`  same question to you.. what is not working?

Comment: You are sending empty strings in your request. That look like a problem, but you do the same in the CURL example. 
Please be more clear about what problem you have.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info to start. I intentionally left the strings blank to hide sensitive data. You can assume that the appropriate information that was successful within the curl request was then placed in the javascript. As far as the specific errors I have been receiving, they have all been status 0. From what I have read so far, I think I have an issue with cross domain scripting, but I am running these scripts from an apache cordova javascript file (which doesnt make sense to me).

Comment: Just thought I would include this, my test scripts work within a api tool called Postman.

Comment: Update: I am getting a 400 error unsupported_grant_type while running my ajax request through a proxy. The request is the same request I have successfully executing in both a curl command and a Postman command.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue, but I cant point to the specific thing I did in order to get it working. I will instead write down everything I did in order to get a working system. My particular example was for an ionic app that used facebook authentication and converted the token to a django csrf token which I used to track users.

My setup: Django, Django rest-framework Social Oauth2 (Philip Garnero's setup), Django social auth, angular js, cordova facebook plugin, ionic (3rd party app that acts as the frontend) and finally a configured proxy service.

Steps: Number one, make sure to have a rest api system installed. I used Philip Garnero's api (1). Once I got the installable package from Garnero in place I had to configure an ionic proxy service. I used Ionic's tutorial to get it in place (2). That document is worth reading to understand the gist of cross domain requests. Finally, what I couldn't find without testing and researching around were the correct headers to attach to the ajax request. I ended up solving it using a very useful tool called Postman.
Here is a dumb example of that "confusingly difficult" request:

```
$http.post(Url, queryStringData,
        {headers: {
              'Accept': '*/*',
              "cache-control": "no-cache",
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }        
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data.access_token);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("error status = " + status);
            console.log(angular.toJson(data));
        });
```

Please comment if you have questions. I will do my best to clean up the original post and may consider a tutorial if others are having the same issues. I spent 5 hours trying to crack this one.

(1)- https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2
(2)- http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/